# How do I adjust the thickness of all the FrameTicks?

Tags: plotting, bugs, style, ticks

I am very sorry if this is trivial, but I can not for the life of me adjust the thickness of *all* tick marks in Plots. Depending on the data to plot, either the top, bottom, top *and* bottom, or top and right ticks stay unaffected. I could not yet find a pattern.
Additionally, the ticks look different, depending if I export as PNG or PDF. I need PDF, so I have attached a screenshot of the PDF output.

So, how do I get all the ticks to look like the thicker ones?

Minimal example:

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,-7,7},Frame->True,FrameStyle->Thickness[.003],FrameTicksStyle->Thickness[.003]]
```

[image]

My actual example:

```
ListLinePlot[CaP,
PlotRange->All,
Frame->True,
FrameLabel->{"\[Nu] / cm^-1","Absorption / a. u."},
FrameStyle->Thickness[.003],
LabelStyle->{12},
FrameTicksStyle->{Directive[FontOpacity->0,FontSize->0,Thickness[.003]],Directive[Thickness[.003],Black]},
AspectRatio->1/2,
ScalingFunctions->{"Reverse"},AxesOrigin->{850,0}
]
```

[image]

That is Mathematica 11. Mathematica 10 generates the same output, but the top ticks are as they should be, only the bottom ticks stay unaffected. Same code.

Comment: I think you're doing this correctly in your first example, all the frame ticks should be thick. This is likely a bug. I see the same behavior on OSX v.11.1.1.0

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154092

Comment: Since the underlying bug is exactly the same as [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57425/280), I'm voting to close this question as a dupe of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the internal functions to create ticks have a hard-coded thickness that overrides the [`FrameTicksStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicksStyle) option. You could work around this by modifying this internal function. The easiest way to do so is to use my [Initial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153885/45431) function, which I reproduce below:

```
Initial /: Verbatim[TagSetDelayed][Initial[sym_], lhs_, rhs_] := With[
    {
    new=Block[{sym},
        TagSetDelayed[sym,lhs,rhs];
        First @ Language`ExtendedDefinition[sym]
    ],
    protect=Unprotect[sym]
    },

    sym;
    Quiet@MakeBoxes[sym[],TraditionalForm];

    Unprotect[sym];
    Replace[
        new,
        Rule[values_,n:Except[{}]] :> (
            values[sym] = DeleteDuplicates @ Join[n, values[sym]]
        ),
        {2}
    ];
    Protect@protect;
]
```

*(updated to modify `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` instead of `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks `` so that both ticks with and without numbers are fixed)*

The internal function that we need to modify is `` Charting`ScaledTicks ``:

```
Initial[Charting`ScaledTicks] /: 
    Charting`ScaledTicks[a__][b___] /; !TrueQ@$Fix := Block[{$Fix=True},
        Charting`ScaledTicks[a][b] /. AbsoluteThickness[.1]->Sequence[]
    ]
```

The above just removes the hard-coded `AbsoluteThickness[.1]`. Now, let's check:

```
GraphicsRow[{
    Plot[
        Sin[x],
        {x,-7,7},
        Frame->True
    ],
    Plot[
        Sin[x],
        {x,-7,7},
        Frame->True,
        FrameStyle->AbsoluteThickness[2]
    ]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: This works for the sine plot, but for my actual example it does not work. The tick marks on the bottom stay unaffected.

Comment: I think doing the exact same thing for Charting`ScaledTicks instead should fix both of them.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This issue is exactly the same as in the following question:

- [Thickness of logarithmic tick marks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57425/280)

Starting from *Mathematica* 11.1 `Plot` uses `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks `` in the default value for `FrameTicks`:

```
Options[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], FrameTicks]
```

> ```
> {FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}]}, 
>                 {Automatic, Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}]}}}
> ```

As a result, the [bug in `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57425/280) now affects also `Plot`. The same type of fix is applicable here:

```
fixTickThickness[gr_] := gr /. f : (_Charting`ScaledTicks | _Charting`ScaledFrameTicks) :>
   (Part[#, ;; , ;; 3] &@*f)
```

Example:

```
$Version

pl = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -7, 7}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], 
   ImageSize -> 400];

Row@{pl, pl // fixTickThickness}
```

> ```
> "11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)"
> ```
>
> [image: output]

---

#### Update

As it is noted in the comments, the above fix needs to be applied to every plot separately what is tedious. Actually one can make this fix permanent by modifying the default value of `DisplayFunction` of `Plot` and other functions affected by this bug:

```
SetOptions[
  Select[Symbol /@ Names["*Plot"], MemberQ[First /@ Options[#], DisplayFunction] &],
  DisplayFunction :>
   (ReplaceAll[#,
      t : (Ticks | FrameTicks -> _) :>
       (t /. f : (_Charting`ScaledTicks | _Charting`ScaledFrameTicks) :>
          (Part[#, ;; , ;; 3] &@*f))] &)];
```

One can add this piece of code to the Kernel's `init.m` file in order to have it loaded automatically when the Kernel starts. But while this demonstrates another approach to the problem, the [solution by Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155296/280) is more direct and should be preferable in this concrete case.

Comment: My answer is a one-time fix to ``Charting`ScaledTicks`` while yours is a post-process step that needs to be done to every plot.

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes, I upvouted your answer before posing mine. Actually it is possible to convert my solution into a on-time fix too, please see the Update section in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like an erroneous `FrameTicks` rule is being put in the full form. You can get around this by doing the following:

```
yourPlot=Plot[
 Sin[x], {x, -7, 7},
 FrameStyle -> Thickness[.003],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicksStyle ->Directive[Thickness[.005]]
 ];


ToExpression@ToBoxes[
    FullForm[yourplot]/.Rule[FrameTicks,_]:>Nothing
]
```

The one bit of trouble here is that this will also delete any `FrameTicks` you specify. If you need custom positioned ticks, you can try:

```
ToExpression@ToBoxes[
    FullForm[yourplot]/.Rule[FrameTicks,_]:>Rule[FrameTicks,yourFrameTicks]
]
```

Without fix:

[image]

With fix:

[image]

Comment: This works, too. Thank you!