# Tick marks don't follow FrameStyle/FrameTicksStyle specs

Tags: graphics

Run the following code and examine the thickness of tick marks carefully in the produced PDFs.

```
lp = LogPlot[Exp[-x], {x, 0, 10},
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[1/2]],
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[1/2]],
   ImageSize -> 160
   ];
Export["lp.pdf", lp]

pp = Plot[-x, {x, 0, 10},
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[1/2]],
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[1/2]],
   ImageSize -> 160
   ];
Export["pp.pdf", pp]
```

In version 12.0.0 on macOS,

- Tick marks are not thick (as they should be) on right and top in Plot.
- They are not thick in left, right and top in LogPlot.

The problem is visible not only in the PDF, but also with `Magnify[lp, 5]`.

Is there a simple workaround? Adding the styles afterwards in `Show` does not help.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thickness of logarithmic tick marks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57425/thickness-of-logarithmic-tick-marks). However, I prefer my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155296/45431) to the duplicate [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155276/45431)